# How do i fetch last occurence of keyword match | Linux |

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I have a scenario which I am implementing

fetch only the last occurrence of matched keyword found

for example : *I have a file called demo.txt contains lots of data*

```
egrep -in '<NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">' /d/demo.txt

Line Number 11 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">
Line Number 12 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">
Line Number 34 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">
Line Number 46 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">
Line Number 67 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">
Line Number 78 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">
```

But I want to fetch the last occurrence of the keyword matched `<NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">`

output should only be

```
Line Number 78 : <NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI"> -> as its last occurrence
```

I tried this below code not working

```
tail -f -n 1 /d/demo.txt | egrep -in '<NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">'
```

Comment: You should describe in more detail what "not working" means. I guess you get no output if the last line of the file doesn't match your pattern.

Comment: The reason why your line is not working is two-fold: for one, you should not use `tail -f`; this is for cases where you want to inspect a file where you expect that some process (e.g. the syslogger) keeps appending text. Second, the order of your commands is wrong: your example would output the last line of `demo.txt` regardless of its content, and the `grep` call would only output anything if the last line happens to contain your pattern. You need to reverse the order: filter your file through `grep` to ensure only matching lines are printed and then use `tail` to show only the last.

Comment: You can probably process the original XML file directly. Is this an XY Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the `tail` after `grep`

```
egrep -in '<NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">' /d/demo.txt | tail -1
```

As you are searching for a literal string, not for an extended regular expresseion, I suggest to use `fgrep` instead of `egrep`.

```
fgrep -in '<NAME ="ABC_DEF_GHI">' /d/demo.txt | tail -1
```

Comment: thank you it worked like a charm

Comment: Can you read another question uploaded @Bodo  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552382/how-to-cut-certain-text-from-file-and-write-to-another-file-linux

Answer (score 0):

To avoid running `grep` on the whole file, reverse it and take the first occurrence:

```
tac file | egrep -in -m1 'pattern'
```

Comment: reversing a big file with `tac` is probably more expensive than `grep` on the whole file.