# How to cut certain text from file and write to another file

Tags: linux, text-processing

The scenario is like I have a file called output.txt

I want certain output to be cut from file and remaining text after cut should be moved to another file

for example : my data in file is like below

```
23: <NAME="ABC_RAM"/> 
24:    <NAME="ABC1"/>
233:      <NAME="ABC_111"/>
300: <NAME="ABC_143"/>
310: <NAME="ABC_XBSKJKSBNSKK"/>
```

I want to cut from `<number : >`  till first symbol `<` 
output should be like below which need to be written to new file

```
<NAME="ABC_RAM"/> 
<NAME="ABC1"/>
<NAME="ABC_111"/>
<NAME="ABC_143"/>
<NAME="ABC_XBSKJKSBNSKK"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:digit:]]+:[[:space:]]+//' file
```